# SQLite freelist: linked list is from the end of the file to the beginning. Why?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm writing a streaming SQLite file parser, and writing the part that deals with the [freelist](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_freelist).

Running the below

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table_1 (my_text_col_a text, my_text_col_b text);
```

and then the below 500k times:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table_1 VALUES ('some-text-a', 'some-text-b');
```

and then

```
DELETE FROM my_table_1;
```

It looks like the freelist forms a chain of trunk pages:
3055, 2037, 1021, 3

I'm surprised (and disappointed?) the linked list forms a chain of pages towards the start of file, rather than towards the end. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make a guess at this: I suspect adding a page to the freelist always adds to the *beginning* of the list, not the end.

This is since adding to the end would involve an O(n) operation, where n is the number of pages in the list so far, since it would have to walk the list to find the last item in the list. However, adding to the beginning would be O(1) since the database header always maintains the page number of the first item in the list.

So, if pages are added to the freelist in *increasing* page num order (e.g. 3, 1021, 2027, 3055), they would appear in the linked list in *decreasing* order, since each is added to the beginning of the existing list.